# How to set Images correctly in Position

Tags: css, html

I'm planning a Enter Page, but I don't know how can I set the positions of my "buttons".

Here is an example of how I would have the position:

[image: Click here]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i didnt got any idea of how i can solve it. so i didnt got a jsfiddle until now.

Comment: BTW - What I meant was that the jsfiddle should include the html structure of your page and the CSS that you tried (Not a working example of-course). There are many ways to solve this

Comment: is this only 4 buttons present in html ? I mean in body tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a square div, positioned in the center of the document. Then use absolute positioning to anchor the buttons to the corners of the div.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}

.container > input { position: absolute; }

.container > input:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container > input:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.container > input:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container > input:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="button" value="Button1">
    <input type="button" value="Button2">
    <input type="button" value="Button3">
    <input type="button" value="Button4">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay this works pretty good. Now i got 2 containers and want to center the buttons only in one of these like this
http://i.stack.imgur.com/dblMi.png

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need? If you don't care about IE 9 and down then flexbox would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I made four buttons in jsfiddle.

```
text-align:center;
```

see it please: https://jsfiddle.net/wLqfv0cx/5/